# Call to a member function insert() on a non-object with wpdb

Tags: php, jquery

i get error Call to a member function insert() on a non-object with wpdb when it calls the mysave.php file, plus how do i get the to use the mysave.php file within the wordpress template folder currently i need to put it to root folder.

```
<style>
form#my > #phase2{ display:none; }
</style>

<script>
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function processPhase1(){
        _("phase1").style.display = "none";
        _("phase2").style.display = "block";        
    } 
function submitForm(){  
            _("myform").method = "post";
            _("myform").action = "mysave.php";
            _("myform").submit();
        }
</script>

        <form id="myform" onsubmit="return false" > 
         <div id="phase1">
        <input type="text" id="inputbook" name="bookname" placeholder="book name" height="34px">
        <button onclick="processPhase1()"><strong>Next</strong></button>
        <div>
        <div id="phase2">
        <input type="text" id="inputcode" name="code" placeholder="code" height="34px">
        <button onclick="submitForm()"><strong>SUBMIT</strong></button>
    <div>
        </form>
```

mysave.php

```
if(isset($_POST['bookname']))
{
    global $wpdb;
    $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];
    $code=$_POST['code'];
    $todaydate = new DateTime();
    $todaydate =$todaydate->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');
    $bookpost= array('post_type'=>'books',
                        'post_title'=>$bookname,
            'post_author'=>'1',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'post_date'=>$todaydate );
    $wpdb->insert('wp_posts',$bookpost); 
    $Cid=$wpdb->insert_id;
    update_field('code',$code,$Cid);
}
```

Comment: Can you add more info about your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template in your mysave.php. Write this code above of your page.

```
<?php
    /**
     * Template Name: Your template name
    */
?>
```

and then go to your wp-admin panel create new page and select your template from drop-down list.